# What is the Azure equivalent of an AWS IAM user for use with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am porting over some infrastructure from AWS to Azure. We deploy everything with full Ansible and Terraform scripts. In AWS I would create an IAM role with the correct/appropriate access (such as create VMs, LBs, Volumes etc) and then use the AccessSecrets on the command line to configure AWS resources.

What is the equivalent way to do this in Azure? I have heard a lot of discussion about using AD, but to my mind AD is for human accounts, not CLI accounts?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you could use `az role assignment create` to do this, for example:

```
az role assignment create --role <role> --assignee-object-id <assignee_object_id> --resource-group <resource_group> --scope </subscriptions/subscription_id>
```

More information about this please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-azure-cli).